# How to append multiple objects in list?

Tags: python, list, append

So, I got this list called `otherlist` and I would like to add a few objects from `list1`. The thing is that I only got their order number, not the actual value of the numbers. For example:

```
otherlist.append(list1[a,a+20,a+20*2,a+20*3])
```

(where `a` is a changing number)
Yeah as you may have noticed we want ever 20th number in the list.

How to do so. I get the error message: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

Answer (score 3):

Python `list` indices cannot be tuples (comma-separated indices); you can only index *one* value at a time.

Use `operator.itemgetter()` to get multiple indices:

```
from operator import itemgetter

otherlist.extend(itemgetter(a, a + 20, a + 20 * 2, a + 20 * 3)(list1))
```

or use a generator expression:

```
otherlist.extend(list1[i] for i in (a, a + 20, a + 20 * 2, a + 20 * 3))
```

or even

```
otherlist.extend(list1[a + 20 * i] for i in range(4))
```

Note that I used `list.extend()` to add individual values to `otherlist`, so that it grows by 4 elements.

Answer (score 3):

Use `list.extend` with a generator expression:

```
my_list.extend(list1[a + 20*i] for i in range(4))
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> lis = []
>>> list1 = range(1000)
>>> a = 2
>>> lis.extend(list1[a + 20*i] for i in range(4))
>>> lis
[2, 22, 42, 62]
```